# Different versions lib in Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, java

We have a Java EE application which is using log4j version 'x' for logging. 
During enhancement of the project I want add the another third party library which is using log4j version 'y'.  I think we need to have both 'x' and 'y' version of library should be added to the classpath.

Can any body please explain how to handle the this kind of scenario?

Comment: Wouldn't it logically make sense to just use the latest version?

Comment: Not sure, all the third party libraries are expected to backward compatible ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have both in the same classloader. You have a to find the version which works for both of your libraries.

If you use maven, you can exclude a transitive dependency this way:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to have 2 different versions of the same jar in your application. As far as log4j is concerned, all 1.x versions are backward compatible, only 2.x ( still in beta ) is not back-ward compatible. So as long as both jar 'x' and jar 'y' belong to the 1.x family, you can use only a single latest version ( 1.2.17 ) without any issue at all.